# Exception thrown at 0x00007FF93F57B016 (ucrtbased.dll) in Ficha 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c

I wrote some code and it showed me this error: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF93F57B016 (ucrtbased.dll) in Ficha 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I can't find the reason behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define num 10

void ler_matriz(int **matriz1, int n, int m);
void mostrar_matriz(int matriz1[num][num], int n, int m);
//int num_min_matriz(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void teste_simetria(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void transposta_matriz(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void soma_matriz(int matriz1[][], int matriz2[][], int matriz3[][], int n, int m);

int main()
{

    int x[num][num], y[num][num], z[num][num], numL, numC;

    printf("Introduza o número de linhas e colunas para a matriz:\n");
    scanf(" %d%d", &numL, &numC);

    printf("\n\nIntroduza os valores para a matriz 1:   ");
    ler_matriz(x, numL, numC);
    mostrar_matriz(x, numL, numC);


    return 0;
}



void ler_matriz(int **matriz1, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("\nx[%d][%d]:    ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf(" %d", &matriz1[i][j]); // the exception error 
        }
    }
}

void mostrar_matriz(int matriz1[num][num], int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d     ", matriz1[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: `int[n][m]` is **not** synonymous with `int **`. Whatever lead you to believe they were is wrong. The former is an array of arrays, the latter is a pointer-to-pointer. Your compiler should have warned you as such. If it didn't, it's time to turn up your warning levels and treat them as errors.

Comment: How can i use the matrix read in the function `ler_matriz()`in the other main functions maintaining the values? (Do i need to use pointers?Or does exist some other way?)

Comment: Look at how `mostrar_matriz` declares it's argument list. That is proper, and works, if the caller size is a native array of arrays (and yours is), and not some manufactured pointer-to-pointer coded pseudonym of a 2D array (which `ler_matriz` expects and you're not giving it). You can't have it both ways. Decide which way you want to do it and uniformly take it from there.

Comment: But if i use it like that, once it enters in that function and i assign the values it doesn't save the values that i need in the matrix to be used by the other functions because every variable used in a function is destroyed after finishing the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
    for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
```

This should be

```
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
```

Otherwise, `i < m` is going to be true forever (because you're not changing `i` in that loop) and you'll eventually be accessing 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (the very edge of memory).

Comment: Didnt notice that but the error happens before enter in that function. It happens after i read the first element of matrix

Answer (score 1):

For memory errors like this a good idea is to use a memory checking tool (you can try valgrind memcheck). Now let's see what's wrong with your code :)

## The array

You have to take into account that `int[m][n]` isn't the same as `int**`. Using the gcc compiler you'll get a warning about it. (Of course, you can alter your code to use `int**`)

## The For Loop

Just as VoteyDisciple said you should be using

```
for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
```

instead of

```
for(int j=0;i<m;j++)
```

## Uninitialized values

Creating an array and not initializing it can lead to memory errors later on (assuming we're talking about C - some languages initialize arrays with 0's). Here you create the `x,y,z` matrixes but you end up using a portion of them which you assign values to. The rest remain uninitialized and you can end up running into errors if you try accessing them later on.

## The scanf exception

Really the exception you get is due to the above, as you're getting errors from trying to access the memory address at `&matriz1[i][j]`

## Fixing it all

Here's how I'd write your code so that it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define num 10

    void ler_matriz(int **matriz1, int n, int m);
    void mostrar_matriz(int** matriz1, int n, int m);
//int num_min_matriz(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void teste_simetria(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void transposta_matriz(int matriz1[][], int n, int m);
//void soma_matriz(int matriz1[][], int matriz2[][], int matriz3[][], int n, int m);

int main()
{

    //int x[num][num], y[num][num], z[num][num], numL, numC;
    int i,j,**x,**y,**z,numL,numC; //Proper declarations
    x=malloc(num*sizeof(int*));
    y=malloc(num*sizeof(int*));
    z=malloc(num*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        x[i]=malloc(num*sizeof(int));
        y[i]=malloc(num*sizeof(int));
        z[i]=malloc(num*sizeof(int));

    }
    //Initialization
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<num;j++) {
            x[i][j]=y[i][j]=z[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    printf("Introduza o número de linhas e colunas para a matriz:\n");
    scanf(" %d%d", &numL, &numC);
    printf("\n\nIntroduza os valores para a matriz 1:   ");
    ler_matriz(x, numL, numC);
    mostrar_matriz(x, numL, numC);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        free(x[i]);
        free(y[i]);
        free(z[i]);
    }
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    return 0;
}



void ler_matriz(int **matriz1, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("\nx[%d][%d]:    ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf(" %d", &matriz1[i][j]); 
        }
    }
}

void mostrar_matriz(int **matriz1, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d     ", matriz1[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: You ought to check the return value of `scanf` too.

Comment: Good point @Bathsheba 
I was way too focused on fixing those memory errors that didn't get too involved with other practices. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer me.
I'm following a book o  C language. I read that arrays can be initialized like this arr[5]={1,2,3} what results in arr[5]={1,2,3,0,0} because the others that i didn't give the value are automatically assigned as zero. So i thought if i can initialize just a part of it by running a for(), all the others index position that hasn't been assigned for me would have been automatically assigned, right? (just needed to give a max range for the array, to not pass the size given)

Comment: Well it's a matter of declaring them. Try declaring 
`int arr1[10]={1,2,3};` and `int arr2[10];` 
Then for arr2 set `arr2[0]=arr2[1]=arr2[2]=1`

Now if you print both arrays from 0 to 9 as to print all their 10 elements for arr1 you'll see 0's but for arr2 you'll see random data.

PS. With dynamic memory allocation, you could just allocate any size the user wants to work with, they'd input the size and it would be used in the calls of malloc().